# Parallelize the function in Python

Tags: python, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

I have a below function that Im trying to parallelize using multiprocessing but I couldn't get it working successful.

```
for d in result_list:
    v=d['content'][0]['template']['module']
    if isinstance(v, list):
        for i, v2 in enumerate(v): 
            df_module,  = normalizeJSON(d,i,v2['id'])
            dim_content_module=dim_content_module.append(df_module, ignore_index=True,sort=False)

    else:
        print('module is not a list')
```

Comment: For starters, why do you use `for index in range(len(result))` instead of `for d in result`? The `index` is not used anywhere, except for retrieving the result from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try Pool from multiprocessing module as following:-

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# function which contain main functional logic
def foo(arg):
    # some processing
    return "return for {}".format(arg)


# function which will invoke multiple processes
def function_which_invokes_multiprocesses(some_arg):
    # pass the number of processes you want to invoke
    with Pool(5) as p:
        invoke the function for each process
        print(foo("some arg"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `result` list or dictionary?

Use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) or [imap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) or async function of both function will be more simple.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

args = [r for r in result]
with Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.map(worker, args)


def worker(d):
    v = d['header'][0]['id']['value']
    if isinstance(v, list):
        for i, v2 in enumerate(v):
            df = function1(d, i, v2['id'])
    return df
```

Comment: result is a list of dict in it

Comment: I tried the above. What's happening is each dict in the result (which is a list of dict) is been proceed by all threads. But what I want is each thread to parallel process the entries in the list. Something like thread 1 doing result[0], thread 2 doing result[1] and so on but append the output of the function1 to the df

Comment: @LisaMathew, Please post the full code or the working sample code.